# How to return 404 by default in Asp Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

I have a simple `Asp Net Web Api`, with one endpoint, and it works well. But I want, when you call root server `(loclahost:8001/)` in my case it returns `404` to me, instead of `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`. I'm new to `ASP NET MVC` and got used to asp net core. Please, how can I return `404` here?

Maybe the route config will help:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "GPayController"}
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration under your `<system.webServer>` section within your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="StopDirectoryBrowsing" path="*." resourceType="Directory" verb="*" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
<system.webServer>
```